# preg_replace for Amazon image url in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Images on Amazon have URL's like this:

```
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/911pRnX5a0L.SL1500.jpg
```

Notice the extra part `._SL1500`, this can vary in numbers and another example is `.SL150`.

I would like to be able to strip this out so we go from:

```
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/911pRnX5a0L.SL????.jpg
```

to just :

```
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/911pRnX5a0L.jpg
```

Any ideas on how I can do this with preg replace or similar in PHP?

Comment: Use something like this: `preg_replace('/\.(SL\d{4})(?=\.jpg$)/', '', $str);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code:

```
<?php
//amazon url
$url = 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/911pRnX5a0L.SL150.jpg';

$pattern = '/\bSL[0-9]+\./i';
$url = preg_replace( $pattern, '', $url );
```

OUTPUT:
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/911pRnX5a0L.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex `~\.SL(.*?)\.~`

```
echo $str = preg_replace("~\.SL(.*?)\.~",".", $str);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/911pRnX5a0L.jpg
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The OP wants to remove the `.SL????` part from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [substr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), this would look something like this:

```
$test = "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/911pRnX5a0L.SL1500.jpg";

$test2 = substr($test,0,-11);

echo "$test2.jpg";
```

Output will be:

`http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/911pRnX5a0L.jpg`

(This will only work if you are sure all images will be .jpg)

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://codepad.org/wBKJrNof)

```
$u =  'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/911pRnX5a0L.SL1500.jpg';
$url =  preg_replace('/SL\d+\./','',$u);
echo $url ;
```